# Search for word within file and display the title of the section containing the word?

Tags: c, string, file, cpu-word

I have to search for a word from a file containing multiple songs, separated by a specific string, and display every song title that contains the word in its lyrics.

The file has the following format:

```
xxxxxxxxxx

song title

Lyrics

xxxxxxxxxx

Song Title

Lyrics

[...]
```

The code I wrote is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/* Note: pif will be function needed to search a word within a generic string */


int main(){
  FILE *fp=fopen("file.txt", "r");
  char line[200],search_string[]="xxxxxxxxxx",word[20],buff[200];
  int cnt=0,flag=0;
  gets(word);
  if (!fp)
    return -1;
  printf("\n\tSongs Containing %s: ", word);
  cnt=0;
  while ( fgets ( line, 200, fp ) != NULL ) /*read a line*/
  {
    if(strstr(line,search_string)){ /*find the separator*/
      fgets(line,200,fp);/*go ahead reading*/
      strcpy(buff,line); /*save the title, which is the very next line after the separator*/
      while(!strstr(line,search_string)){ /* while the lyrics do not match with another 
                                             separator go ahead reading*/
        fgets(line,200,fp);
        if(pif(line,word)) /*using the defined *pif* function (required), I'd find *word* 
                             within the line */
           flag=1;
      }
      if(flag)
         printf("%s", buff);
     
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);

  return 1;
}
```

Is there anyway I can make this whole stuff working? The output displays each song titles instead of specific ones.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  An [mcve] would also include a minimal input example(s), not pseudo code for the layout of it.  We should be able to cut and paste from your post and duplicate your issue, without having to guess what is going on.  Please [edit] your post.

Comment: *Never* use `gets`.  It's not even in the language anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`if(flag)  printf("%s", buff);  break;` this should break after printing the very first song, but you're saying it's not.. so I think you've a typo in post..

now your code.. After you set your flag to 1 after you found a match, then you are not setting it back to zero even after printing the string. As your inner while iterates through the complete song, the print is done at the start of next song, where you should set `flag=0;` or else even if that word is not in the song, as flag remains 1, the song name is printed.

```c
      if(flag)
      {
         printf("%s", buff);
         flag=0;
      }
```

This should work.

*note: all of this assumes your pif function is working properly.*

Answer (score 0):

Its just an issue of not resting your flag to 0 before your next check. Right now, every title that occurs after the first song that has the matching world will be printed. If your problem still persists it might have something to do with the pif function. Please do share if you do not get this right !!